# Add tree as a sub tree to different type of tree

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have tree, **T**, structure in an Eclipse plugin which has a different type of parent or node. Now I want to add a tree, **T1**, to it which has a node of a different type. So what would be the clear and robust approach to do this task as it is assumed that it would get a lots of load so approach should be very visionary?

**My approach:** As I am very new in this, in my opinion I have to just manage (anyhow) the `getParent()` method for **T1** of same type to **T**, as this would be the down most sub tree of tree **T**.

(I want to ask this question for a discussion point of view. I want to just clear my views and approach.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make/use a tree interface or abstract class that all the other trees implement/extend, then create a list of that interface or abstract class. E.g:

```
ArrayList<TreeInterface> treeArray = new ArrayList<TreeInterface>();
```

This interface/abstract class should have all of the methods, getters and setters you will need to access the data you want later on.

If you can't do that, I think you can only make an array of Object to satisfy this...